# Formatting toString() - New Lines

Tags: java

I'm building a console based inventory program and would like to override the toString() method to print the customer object to the screen.

I've got the following to approaches but they both look pretty messy. Which one is better practice?

```
String toString = (name + newLine +
                       addressLine_1 + newLine + 
                       addressLine_2 + newLine + 
                       city + newLine + 
                       country + newLine +
                       postCode + newLine);


String toString = System.out.println(String.format("%s%n%s%n%s**%n%s%n%s%n%s%n", name, addressLine_1, addressLine_2, city, country, postCode));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use A String Builder!

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
strBuilder.append( name );
strBuilder.append( System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) );
strBuilder.append( addressLine_1 );
/* ... */

System.out.println( strBuilder.toString() );
return strBuilder.toString();
```

Using a `StringBuilder` ( or a `StringBuffer` for older versions of the JDK ) is not only more readable, it also makes string concatenation more efficient. Also, use `System.getProperty( "line.separator" )` to ensure cross-platform line endings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some ToString utilities to make the job easier. I know two variants:

- apache commons: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html
- google guava http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.ToStringHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

The first one is preferred.

Chances are, your program may be enhanced in near future to output complex objects e.g. `Person`, it is much cleaner and maintainable to go with the first approach.

The String concatenation + .. + isn't much of a performance issue. Until then, you may further continue using `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` (if you are on JDK < 5)

Comment: +1, for suggesting the `StringBuffer` for older versions of JDK, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get the system dependent line separator with:

```
System.lineSeparator();
```

Answer (score 0):

New lines can be created using `\n`.

Comment: Using `System.getProperty( "line.separator" )` is more cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use StringBuilder. The + each time creates a new string -  not the good practice. Just override function toString() with StringBuilder.